Next-auth redirects to home on wrong credentials with CredentialsProvider
I'm having trouble with next-auth and NextJS 14.
On desktop all is fine, on mobile (at least every iOS device I had available) there is an issue with wrong redirects.
When the user performs a login with a wrong username/password credentials the login page is shown with the correct error message. The URL gets the correct parameter passed with the error code.
But on iOS, I'm redirected towards the homepage of the application without seeing any error message (nor a search parameter with the error code).
This the config for next-auth.
export const authOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: JWT; user: AppUser }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      token.account = {};
      return token;
    },
    async session({
      session,
      token,
      user,
    }: {
      session: AppSession;
      token: JWT;
      user: NextAuthUser;
    }) {
      session.user = token.user as AppUser;
      return session;
    },
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        ...
        if (passwordCorrect) {
          ...
          return user;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
};

